# not to show full URL on webpage by modifying sql query

Tags: sql, hyperlink, ssms

I created select query in SQL Server Management Studio. One was hyperlink. The hyperlink was clickable. However, the full URL was shown on webpage. Does anyone know how to modify the code below in order not to show full URL? Thanks.

```
'http://companyname' + Substring(lastPDF.[PDFPath], 14, 50) AS PDFTest
```

Comment: Please describe the output you got so far and the output you are expecting

Comment: [Current output] PDFTest: http://companyname/pdfmedia/a00001.pdf  [Expected output] PDFTest: more info